# Using list of attributes to create layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a very long list of values (over 2000 rows) in the following format:

```
1: TAY100, AB60, EM10
2: CA40, 9, UT26, 24
3: YO56, YE
```

I have a layer with features each with a distinct attribute called VistaID that looks like this:

[image]

How can I create a layer with the name of the number on the left that includes the features with VistaIDs that correspond to the values in the list?

In other words, how can I create a layer called 1 that includes the features that have the VistaIDs of TAY100, AB60, and EM10, and then repeat this for every row?

Comment: It looks u just have to do a **join between two tables** but the structure of your two data sources look quite different : will **VistaID** be found **as is** in your first list or a kind of **substring** has to be found ? My first step would be to build a table with the data of your first list ...

Comment: @snaileater Is there an easy way to put that list into a table in QGIS?  I have the ability to put that list into a .csv, so would that be importable into QGIS?